# How do I download a generated csv in magento 2.4.5

Tags: csv, magento2.4

My files so far are:

system.xml

```
<field id="generate_csv" translate="label" type="button" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
   <label>Generate Categories CSV</label>
  <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Button</frontend_model>
</field>
```

button.php

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Button extends Field
{
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::system/config/button.phtml';

    public function __construct(
        Context $context, 
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }

    public function getAjaxUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('[router]/Export/CategoryExport');
    }

    public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button'
        )->setData(
            [
                'id' => 'generate_csv', 
                'label' => __('Generate CSV')
            ]
        );
        return $button->toHtml();
    }
}
```

button.phtml

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'prototype'
    ], function ($) {

        $('#generate_csv').click(function () {
            var params = {};
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl() ?>', {
                parameters: params,
                loaderArea: false,
                asynchronous: true,
                onCreate: function () {
                    $('#custom_button_response_message').text('');
                },
                onSuccess: function (transport) {
                    var resultText = '';
                    if (transport.status > 200) {
                        resultText = transport.statusText;
                    } else {
                        var response = JSON.parse(transport.responseText);
                        resultText = response.message
                    }
                    $('#generate_csv_response_message').text(resultText);

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<?php echo $block->getButtonHtml(); ?>
<p>
    <span id="generate_csv_response_message"></span>
</p>
```

controller

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Controller\Adminhtml\Export;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;

class CategoryExport extends Action
{
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        DirectoryList $directoryList,
        CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ){
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
        $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return Json
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $message = 'Success';
        $data[] = [
            'id' => __('Entity ID'),
            'name' => __('Name'),
            'level' => __('Level')
        ]; 

        $categoryCollection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $filepath = 'export/customerlist.csv';
        $this->directory->create('export');
        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();
        $header = ['Id', 'Name', 'Level'];
        $stream->writeCsv($header);

        //$categoryArray = array();
        foreach ($categoryCollection as $category) {
            $data = [];
            $data[] = $category->getId();
            $data[] = $category->getName();
            $data[] = $category->getLevel();
            $stream->writeCsv($data);
        }

        /** @var Json $result */
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

        return $result->setData(['message' => $message]);
    }

    
}
```

This creates a csv file in var/export directory but I cannot download it
Can anyone help explain how to modify the code so that it will automatically create and down the csv.

I have tried following various examples on the web but none of them have worked.

Please help me out

Comment: Does this link help?: [Magento2 file download action](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96971/magento2-file-download-action)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).